# UML Figuring out my class diagram

Tags: c#, uml, class-diagram

I have a weird system and I wondered how I'd lay it out in a class diagram, this is an system for a small college project

For simplicity, I have two halves of my system, a "Members" side and a "Race" side, the members side is used by Member Secretaries, and the Race side is used by Race Secretaries, the chairman of the company can access the whole system whereas each Secretary only has one respective half of the system they access via a GUI.

- There is a BaseRace class which stores all race information, but not the functions that modify this information.
- There is also an Organiser, which extends the functionality of Race Secretary, but has limited functionality (not as much methods accessible to them)
- There is also a BaseMember class and this has three subclasses which hold member information, these are members and they have a lower permissions level than Secretaries (Junior,Senior,Support)

The way I set out the separate Race and Member interaction **methods** was, I made a RaceFunctions class and a MemberFunctions class which store both the member functions (add, remove, edit) and the race functions (add, remove, edit).

This way, the chairman can access both classes, and the Secretaries only access one.

- Is this correct?
- If so, how would I lay these out in a class diagram?

Please keep in mind I have no code yet and this is my initial class diagram.

Comment: If your design describes all the important aspects of the modeled reality then it is correct. In UML class diagram you **start by drawing** each class as   it's own [rectangle](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/class-diagrams.html), preferably using an [UML modeling tool](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools). What's your practical answerable [on-topic question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)? Stack Overflow is not discussion forum..

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I would do to maximize code reuse and keep the design simple:

- Make a single class with access to all items (the chairman)
- Put all of you create, read, update, delete logic in the chairman class only
- Create a class for each of the restricted users (secretaries and the organizer) and set the chairman class as an attribute in each of them. Then call (proxy) the methods you need from the chairman class in the restricted class.

This will make it so you only have to write the code once in the chairman class and then pass the code to each one of the restricted entities.

See [Proxy pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_pattern) for more information on using proxies

Comment: Also, I would have classes with more privileges realize the classes with less privileges. For example Race Secretary would realize Organizer. This allows you to reuse the logic in the Organizer in the Race Secretary class.

Comment: I'm pretty new to UML modeling and OO, I've never heard of proxies before.

Is there any other way to do this with basic inheritance, aggregation and other simple ways?

Code reuse is great, but I'm just looking for a basic system here.

Answer (score 0):

> I made a RaceFunctions and a MemberFunctions class which store both the member functions (add, remove, edit) and the race functions (add, remove, edit).

I would not put any such class like `RaceFunctions` or `MemberFunctions` into a UML class diagram. Also I do not understand why you create classes named `BaseRace` or `BaseMember`.

It is hard to understand the desired system functionality from your short description, but in a class diagram you should concentrate on defining proper terminology for your planned system. It is not so important what person will be using whatever class in your system when you are making UML class diagram. The class diagram shows how data are named and organized within your system.

It seems to me that you mix the Class diagram with Use case diagram. In Use case diagram you model how the various parts of your system will be used and eventually by whom (actor).

As you put it I see only two classes in your system: `Race` and `Member`. You can also add classes like `User`, `Action`, `AllowedUsersAction` to store user's access rights. There is no need to create a separate class (`Organiser,`) just because it would be used only by certain users.